# Editar BBDD Sqlite a traves de Excel o similar

Tags: excel, sqlite, odbc

Tengo determinada informacion almacenada en una BBDD SQLite. Estoy buscando una manera de poder conectarla a una herramienta como Excel (no tiene por que ser Excel, aunque seria preferible) y poder editar la BBDD desde ahi sin tener que utilizar comandos update y commit. Es esto posible?
La conexion Excel-BBDD SQLite ya la he establecido de tal manera que puedo ver los contenidos de la BBDD en Excel, pero no encuentro manera de editarlos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: falto poner el código que tienes, sin eso es difícil ayudar, pero es claro que si requieres actualizar registros, evidentemente hay que usar UPDATE, en excel puedes trabajar con ADO para conectarte a sqlite y trabajar con la base de datos.

Answer (score -1):

Al menos desde Excel, no lo veo posible. Incluso desde herramientas nativas de Microsoft como Access, al vincular los datos Excel, Microsoft indica: "Si desea agregar, editar o eliminar datos, debe realizar los cambios en el archivo de origen."
Dicho esto, en tu caso será igual. Ten en cuenta que dichas vinculaciones o datos externos, son tratados como copias del original.
De cualquier modo, si explicas el objetivo de que tu BBDD SQLite tenga que ser editada de manera externa por un Excel o similar, igual alguien te podría aportar una solución. Entendiendo por similar otro programa, que seguramente nada tenga que ver con Excel, dado lo peculiar que es.